# 'IDTExtensibility2' is ambiguous in the namespace 'Extensibility'

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to build a COM Add-In and I get the errors:

```
'IDTExtensibility2' is ambiguous in the namespace 'Extensibility'.
'ext_DisconnectMode' is ambiguous in the namespace 'Extensibility'.
'ext_ConnectMode' is ambiguous in the namespace 'Extensibility'.
```

My imports are as follows:

```
Imports Extensibility
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
Imports Microsoft.Office.Core
```

I used the shared add-in wizard in VS 2010 and I am using VB.NET.

The codes that have errors are anything that contains:

```
Extensibility.IDTExtensibility2
```

I couldn't find this anywhere and I figured the wizard would work without errors. Any thoughts? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether one of the Microsoft.* namespaces already imports the Extensibility namespace.

If not, there is possibly an upper-/lowercase ambiguity, try whether you can access the class in C# or through reflection.

If it still does not works, there probably goes something wrong during interop proxy generation but then it get's complicated, you have to use the tlbimp.exe tool and toy around with its options.

Comment: Thank you sir, I took out all imports and still get the error. However, I did go into my own references in the project properties menu and started removing references. The one that I removed was "MSADDNDR.DLL" which is the Microsoft Add-in Designer. I guess it was already added in the imports...

I'll run a build and see if it works.